# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'arg1'

Tags: python

I m new to python and was trying to figure how a class works
this is my code which is fairly simple but I keep getting the AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'arg1' whenever i run it.

```
class testclass:
    def testmethod(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
p = testclass().testmethod("input1", "input2")
print(p.arg1)
```

I know it been posted a million times by now but I just can't figure this one out

Comment: [Python, creating objects](//stackoverflow.com/q/15081542)

Comment: `testmethod` returns `None`, so you are storing `None` to the variable `p` and then trying to access `.arg1`, which will raise the error you're seeing

Comment: @user22341 You should also consider using the `constructor` to intialize your attributes rather than initializing in a `testmethod`.

Comment: yeah i know i can use a constructor. i was just trying stuff out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `methods` of `function` don't `return` anything, by `default` it `return` `None`, in your case when you make:

```
p = testclass.testmethod('input', 'input'2)
```

You assign to `p` variable `None` because `testmethod` don't return anything, if you use this case you can return `self` to get the `self` `object`.

```
class testclass:
    def testmethod(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
        return self
p = testclass().testmethod("input1", "input2")
print(p.arg1)
```

**Output**

```
input1
```

But i think better to use `constructor`, the `__init__` method.

```
class testclass:
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2):
        self.arg1 = arg1
        self.arg2 = arg2
p = testclass("input1", "input2")
print(p.arg1)
```

Comment: ok i added the "return self" at the end of the method and now it works!
however i dont understand why i have to do this?